# Finding non specific values from an array in another array in Excel Vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Ok I have done alot of researching on this topic and I havent been able to find an answer so here it goes:
I have data that I am receiving in an order that is undesirable (just columns with headings such as date,time etc. and data beneath these headings) my goal is to sort the undesired data from a template that has already been sorted by hand (in another worksheet).  My current idea is to use something like this to specify the two arrays:

```
SetRng1 = Application.InputBox("Select The Formatted Range of Channel Names", Type:=8)

SetRng2 = Application.InputBox("Select The Unformatted Range of Channel Names", Type:=8)
```

Using Rng1 elements to sort Rng2 elements.  However the channels in Rng1 will not always be in Rng2 and in this case the channel from the formatted data (Rng1) will need to be inserted in the correct order with blank cells beneath it. As is the case in Rng2 where there will be channels that are not in Rng1, these will need to be pushed to the end of the channel list. Also the names and number of headings in Rng1 and Rng2 will always be changing so elements cannot be found and sorted simply by their channel name.  I am ashamed to admit that my knowledge of vba is not up to par for this task. I appreciate any help that may be provided and please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Can you show us a snapshot or link to your input data as well as expected outcome with some sample data? From what is mentioned, you want to append array 2 data that are not in array 1 into array 1 and vise versa. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer.**  It is attempt to understand your question behind which I suspect is an interesting problem.  You should copy the correct guesses about your problem from this text to your question and replace the incorrect guesses.

You cannot keep data in arrays so you must be describing the middle of the problem. I guess you have a worksheet containing the formatted data and from time-to-time you receive a CSV file of new data which is to be merged into the worksheet.

To make descriptions easier, I will use this to represent your formatted data:

```
Name   Week  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri
John      1    5   10   12   4     3
Gwen      1    3   15    3   1     8
John      2    3    7   18   6     4
Gwen      2    9   20    4   1     7
```

You say the formatted names may change or be added to.  Perhaps the boss decides Mon, Tue, etc. is too informal and wants the week names spelt out.  Perhaps you add Saturday and Sunday and get into arguments about whether Sunday is the first or the last day of the week.

You say the column headings in the CSV file do not always matches the formatted column headings.  Perhaps the CSV headings are abbreviated when the formatted ones are not.  Perhaps the CSV headings are in Spanish.  Perhaps there is a public holday during a rush period so John and Gwen work Tuesday to Saturday.  Perhaps Friday is the Sabbath for a new member of staff so they work Sunday to Thursday.

You are thinking about using `InputBox` to get the user to select the two heading sequences but I cannot see how that would work.

Firstly, you can look at the worksheet to find the desired sequence.  The user does not have to select anything.

Secondly, for the user to select a name set and sequence for the CSV file means the macro must hold a list of all possible name sets and sequences.  Is that possible?  Since you state the CSV file may include a new heading, I would guess not.

Suppose, the two sets of headings are:

```
Worksheet: Name   Week  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri
 CSV file: Staff  WoY   Sun  Mon  Teu  Wed  Sat
```

There are different names for the Name and Week columns.  There are different weekdays with the complication that Tuesday has been misspelt.

Will you have a prepared list matching the CSV file?  Will you attempt to fix differences on the fly?  I do not think a complete set of prepared lists is possible.  The second will require some clever and complicated code for limited benefit.

I would (1) simplify the requirement and (2) have a prepared table of alternative names.

To simplify, I would require the formatted data include every possible column in advance.  If a CSV file contains the previously unknown Saturday, I would require it be added before the CSV file is applied.  I would not try to add "Teu" if it was not in the list.

My table of alternatives would be in a hidden worksheet and be something like this where every row defines a list of alternative names for the same column:

```
Name   Staff      Staff member
Week   WoY        Week of year
Mon    Monday     M
Tue    Tuesday    Tu            Teu
Wed    Wednesday  W
Thu    Thursday   Th
Fri    Friday     F
Sat    Saturday   Sa            St
Sun    Sunday     Su            Sn
```

This table cannot handle ambiguities.  Given `M  T  W  T  F`, it could not deduce that the first `T` is Tuesday and the second Thursday.

You can include mispellings (such as `Teu`) if you wish.

I would require every column header from both the worksheet and the CSV file be in this table.  Any unrecognised column header would result in a helpful message so the user could fix the worksheet, the table of alternatives or the CSV file before rerunning the macro.

It should be clear that although you may have a VBA problem I think you have a design problem first.

Good luck.